# Convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to yyyymmddhhmmss in R

Tags: r, arrays, string, datetime

I have a data `x`. It has a column `time`.
This column has yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss expression.
[image]

I want make this column has yyyymmddhhmmss expression.
For example, `2021-12-01 00:00:00` should be `20211201000000`.
I use R programming. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete non-digits.

```
gsub('\\D', '', '2021-12-01 00:00:00')
# [1] "20211201000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `format` after converting to `Datetime` class

```
x$time <- format(as.POSIXct(x$time), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```